# What is the RecylerView Adapter responsible for? Select each of the following true statements:

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

1. Creating a ViewHolder object for each RecylerView item.
2. Caching the views associated with each item.
3. Returning the number of item in the data source.
4. Binding data from the data source to each item.
5. Recycling item so they can be used again.
6. Inflating each item view that will be display.

This is question from udacity and I am unable to answer it. According to my learning it's 1,4,5,6 but it's wrong.
Actual question is here you can try it.
[Question](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud851/lessons/c81cb722-d20a-495a-83c6-6890a6142aac/concepts/ac437863-ae9d-4a89-a935-10de8d5ffbaa#)

Comment: It might help to look at the JavaDoc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html ... Tip: getItemCount()

Comment: @Ridcully i also tried 3rd option but it's again worng.

Comment: I tried the question from your link and got it right with my first attempt :-) Are you sure about 1,4,5 and 6? Think about what each means exactly and if the Adapter really does it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The adapter of recylerview is reposible for

1. Creating a ViewHolder object for each RecylerView item.
2. Returning the number of item in the data source.
3. Binding data from the data source to each item.
4. Inflating each item view that will be display.

You can check from the link [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Comment: what about binding logic to onclick listeners?